# Right triangle problem. Might be unsolvable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkEVq.jpg

Find the length PQ if R=3490.

Am I correct in assuming there is no solution to this problem without at least one angle measurement besides the 90 degrees? The whole problem wants me to find a formula for PQ and plot it. While we could find a formula for PQ you can't plot it with just symbols...

Comment: The blue line represents a sphere. Is it possible to get an angle measurement off of that?

Comment: What is the real problem?  You are correct that you need another piece of information to find PQ, but when you talk about finding a formula and plotting  you can do that.  For example, you could find PQ as a function of the angle at the bottom and plot the result.  The angle becomes the independent variable, PQ the dependent variable, and you can plot the relationship.

Comment: Give the formula for length PQ of the shortest visible object (in miles) as a function of x measured in miles.

Comment: Interpret this diagram as follows:
You are positioned at the origin on the surface of the earth, and the x -axis represents your line of sight. C represents the center of the earth, and R is the radius of the earth. At a horizontal distance x miles from your position is the point Q . At that distance you can see nothing of height less than the length of the line segment PQ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is the coordinate of $Q$ you have a right triangle so $(R+PQ)^2=x^2+R^2$.  Solve that for $PQ$ and you can plot $PQ$ as a function of $x$.  It is a quadratic, or you can just use algebra to unpack PQ.